# select last record in each group for large database

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to fetch last record in each group. I have used following query with very small database and it works perfectly -

```
SELECT * FROM logs 
WHERE id IN (
     SELECT max(id) FROM logs 
     WHERE id_search_option = 31 
     GROUP BY items_id
    ) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

But when it comes to actual database having millions of rows (**`80,00000+ rows`**), the system gets hanged.

I also tried another query, which gives result in **`6.6sec`** on an average --

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.itemtype, p1.items_id, p1.date_mod
FROM logs p1
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT max(id) as max_id, itemtype, items_id, date_mod 
     FROM logs 
     WHERE id_search_option = 31 
     GROUP BY items_id) p2
ON (p1.id = p2.max_id) 
ORDER BY p1.items_id DESC;
```

Please help !

**EDIT:: Explain 2nd query**

```
id  select_type     table     type    possible_keys     key     key_len     ref       rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>     ALL     NULL             NULL     NULL       NULL      1177    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY     p1            eq_ref   PRIMARY          PRIMARY   4        p2.max_id    1   
2   DERIVED     logs           ALL     NULL             NULL     NULL      NULL      7930527   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: Could you please show the explain result of the 2nd query ? `explain select....` I presume its missing the indexes and perhaps the following index would help it out. `alter table logs add index opt_items_id_idx(id_search_option,items_id)`

Comment: what indexes exist on the table now? please list them in the question. suggest: remove `itemtype,` and `, date_mod` from the select clause  of the subquery, they are not used (and will not be reliable anyway)

Comment: @Anonymous just create the index as I mentioned and make sure to take a backup before adding the index, and then see the query performance.

Answer (score -1):

select *from tablename orderby unique_column desc limit 0,1;
try it will work
here 0->oth record,1->one record

Comment: @Malli- did you read my question clearly ? I need to get latest data for each group